# How to search through a client Address details LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to figure out a way to search through a User's contact details.

User can have more than one Contact

Here is my code:

```
_usersRep.Find(r=>(string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.PhoneNumber) 
               || r.UserContacts
                      .Select(o => o.TelephoneNo)
                      .Contains(vm.PhoneNumber))
```

This should bring back me the user that any of its contact contains the PhoneNumber that I pass it to it. I actually tried to find where it should be equal but I could not get it worked.

I have checked on the database that this user has a contact object and that contac object phone number is the one that I search for but it does not bring me the user.

The relationship between `User` and `UserContacts` is one to many.

I also would like to ignore the search filter if the text is empty? But when I do not type anything it brings me all users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like:

```
_usersRep.Where(r => r.UserContacts.Any(uc => uc.TelephoneNo == vm.PhoneNumber))
```

So restricting which users are returned (Where clause) based on whether the user has Any usercontacts with a matching number.

**EDIT** multiple conditions:

```
_usersRep.Where(r => r.UserContacts.Any(uc => uc.TelephoneNo == vm.PhoneNumber &&
                                              uc.EmailAddress == vm.EmailAddress)) // etc
```

So the logic is, for each UserContact we test, if ALL the conditions are true in the lambda expression, then it passes the predicate, in which case as we are using the Any test, the userRep is selected. Hope this makes sense!

**OK** so if some of the fields can legitimately be empty, we should make sure the filter is defined if we do a compare, so combining in some nested `ORs` works here:

```
_usersRep.Where(r => r.UserContacts.Any(uc => 
    (String.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.PhoneNumber) || uc.TelephoneNo == vm.PhoneNumber) &&
    (String.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.EmailAddress) || uc.EmailAddress == vm.EmailAddress)))
```

Note that if **all** fields in vm are blank, this will bring back everything, as there is no restriction. If you don't want this, you should probably check *before* calling this query.

**Explanation**

Just to make it clear how this works. If we take the basic clause for each field:

```
(String.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.PhoneNumber) || uc.TelephoneNo == vm.PhoneNumber)
```

We are saying if part `A` or `B` is true, then *for this field* we have a match. Note that the `||` operator evaluates `A` first, and only evaluates `B` if `A` is false. So, in plain English, if `String.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.PhoneNumber)` is `true` (ie if the user doesn't enter query text for this field) then it is a match, no matter what the `PhoneNumber`s actually are. So therefore we only test `uc.TelephoneNo == vm.PhoneNumber` when something was specified for `vm.PhoneNumber`

So the above determines that for a single field we have a match (either because the user didn't enter a query for this field, or because they did, and the strings match). Now we use the `&&` to ensure that every field we are checking is a match based on the above test.

Now because we do `String.IsNullOrEmpty` first for every field in our filter, if this is true for *every* field, based on the above logic, everything is a match. This makes semantic sense as well - if you don't enter any terms to restrict the search, you would expect to receive everything.

If the above is a problem in your case, as I said before I would check this before you execute the query, and tell the user that they must enter *at least one* search term to restrict the search.

Comment: But I have more than one filter. SO how Do I chain them if I use Where clouse?

Comment: Do you mean `IsNullOrEmpty`? That's actually not needed, because, assuming your UC `TelephoneNo` will never be legitimately null or empty, nothing will match if `vm.PhoneNumber` is null

Comment: No I mean I have other filter like email address as well. so it should be && by email address too. it should only bring result back where uc.EmailAddress==vm.EmailAddress plus uc.LandLineNumber==vm.LandLineNumber ...so on. but it should && the results not combine

Comment: So you want all user contacts where all the conditions are met per user contact? I'll edit that above

Comment: I want all users where all the search filters (conditions are met) :)

Comment: And if the filter is empty basically user did not type anything then that filter should be opted out and it should not apply that filter.

Comment: Where all the search filter conditions are met, for at least one contact, right? not for ALL contacts?

Comment: Yes thats correct if filter matches any of the contacts of that user it will bring that user as a result. even it it matches of the user contacts it will bring that user.

Comment: It works but it doesnt work if the email address is not empty. Basically it still filters and && the result against empty email address. So there must be a logic to say if the filter is empty just ignore the filter. At the moment it seems to be checking it against empty text and if the email address it not empty then the return result does not contain any user at all.

Comment: So if a field is empty, then even if match text has been entered in vm.Whatever, it must still be considered?

Comment: so if there are 2 users and both has 2 contact cards. In the user interface you cna type and search by email address, mobile number, telephone number. so if both users have the same mobile number in theier contact details the result should bring both user back. If the user types email address and mobile number then any user has the typed email address and mobile number will be returned as a result. If I leave any filter empty those filters should be ignored. I hope this is clear

Comment: And also yes as you said that if all are empty it brings all result. The way I solved that issue that I first checked al filters whether empty or not then if all empty return null if not apply the filter. Not sure this is the best approach in this but it works anyway thanks

Comment: For the future reference could you please describe the logic a bit in plain english? I cannot read that logic. And why if the all filters are empty it brings back all the users? Thank you very much again

Comment: Done - although it is difficult to judge what level to aim at when explaining such logic. I hope this helps you to make progress!

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris for the clear explanation. Now it makes sense. I am sure this is another question actually to check let say I have a modelfilter which has 10 properties (fields) in it. it would not be nice to check all by using string.isnullorempty(filter1) .. string.isnullorempty(filter2... then if all properties empty then return no result found. there must be a way to check all those in one go.. or not. maybe as someone else suggested that to use reflection. Thanks for the answer again. it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that `vm.PhoneNumber` is your search filter, add `!` to `String.IsNullOrEmpty` check and change `||` to `&&`

```
_usersRep.Find(r=>(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.PhoneNumber) 
           && r.UserContacts
                  .Select(o => o.TelephoneNo)
                  .Contains(vm.PhoneNumber))
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting all of the users when the search string is because of this

```
_usersRep.Find(r=>(string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.PhoneNumber) || ... )
```

If the phone number string is null or empty then the find will always return true, giving you all of the users

you want

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.PhoneNumber))
          _usersRep.Find(r=> ... )
```

For the other problem, try trimming your string

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.PhoneNumber))
    _usersRep.Find(r=>r.UserContacts
                      .Select(o => o.TelephoneNo)
                      .Contains(vm.PhoneNumber.Trim()))
```

Besides those changes don't notice anything else that should be giving you problems.